# EC2 instance not registering with ECS when no public IP is assigned to the EC2 instance while creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

When I create an EC2 instance and I set "Auto-assign Public IP" to Enable and set User Data below. EC2 instance does get registered with ECS.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=mytestcp >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
```

But when I set "Auto-assign Public IP" to Disable the EC2 instance does not get registered with the EC2 instance.

What setting would I need to do extra so that instances can register with ECS without public IP?

Answer (score 5):

Without a public IP, the EC2 instance cannot access anything that exists outside the VPC. This includes things like the AWS API. You either need to place the EC2 instance in a private VPC subnet that has a route to a NAT Gateway, or you need to setup [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html) for all the AWS services like ECS and ECR that the server needs to access.